# Proper usage of JDBC Connection Pool (Glassfish)

Tags: java, jdbc, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

I need a database connection in Java Web service implemented as a session bean, and I'm not sure if I do it right.

I created a class

```
public final class SQLUtils   {  
    //.....  
    private static DataSource  m_ds=null;    

    static  
    {  
        try
        {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            m_ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup(dbName); //Connection pool and jdbc resource previously created in Glassfish  , dbName contains the proper JNDI resource name 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            m_ds = null;
        }

    }

    public static Connection getSQLConnection() throws SQLException  
    {  
        return m_ds.getConnection();             
    }
}
```

Whenever I need a connection I do

```
 Connection cn = null;  
 try  
 {
     cn = SQLUtils.getSQLConnection();
     // use connection
 }
 finally 
 {
     if (null != cn)
     {
         try
         {
             cn.close();
         }
         catch (SQLException e)
         {

         }
     }
 }
```

Is it ok to use it this way, or I DataSource must be a member of the bean ?

```
  @Stateless  
  @WebService  
  public class TestBean  {  
   private @Resource(name=dbName) DataSource m_ds;   
  }
```

I'm sorry if it is a nube question, but I'm pretty new to Java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apart from the C-style formatting, a few unnecessary lines and a bit poor exception handling, you can just do so.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
public final class SQLUtil {
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    // ..

    static {
        try {
            dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(name);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {  
        return dataSource.getConnection();             
    }
}
```

I throw here [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) so that the application will immediately stop so that you don't need to face "unexplainable" `NullPointerException` when trying to obtain a connection.

Comment: I would however favor the injection in the bean itself because it's easier to mock and to test.

Comment: As Pascal pointed out, you actually don't need all that stuff. Just a `@Resource` is enough.

Answer (score 11):

In the ancient J2EE world, the traditional way to manage this was to use a `ServiceLocator`. Below, a sample implementation (non optimized, the `DataSource` could be cached):

```
public class ServiceLocator {
    private Context initalContext;

    private static ServiceLocator ourInstance = new ServiceLocator();

    public static ServiceLocator getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private ServiceLocator() {
        try {
            this.initalContext = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new ServiceLocatorException(...);
        }
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource(String dataSourceName) {
        DataSource datasource = null;

        try {
            Context ctx = (Context) initalContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            datasource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(dataSourceName);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new ServiceLocatorException(...);
        }

        return datasource;
    }
}
```

To use it, simply call it like this:

```
DataSource ds = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getDataSource("jdbc/mydatabase");
```

But this was prior to the EJB3 and Dependency Injection era. Now, when using EJB3, if you have setup your `DataSource` in your EJB container, **all you have to do to automatically inject the `DataSource` in your Stateless Bean is to write** (where `mydatabase` is the name of the datasource):

```
@Resource
private DataSource mydatabase;
```

Use the name attribute if you want to explicitly, well, set the name:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/mydatabase")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

EJB3 actually make the `ServiceLocator` pattern obsolete and you should really prefer injection when working with them.

Comment: Ah drat, I *knew* it. That's indeed **much** better than some helper class. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Um, isn't this an example to a **JDBC DataSource**, not a **Glassfish Connection Pool**?