# When destroy the database connection?

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

I'm working on a project programmed in jsf, but no persistence layer, the queries are plain jdbc in beans. At apllication start the jdbc connection is instantiated and if the user exists und writes his correct password the authentification bean will be instantiated. My problem is, I don't know exactly how to destroy the connection wenn the authentification bean dies for example because of a timeout. My other problem is, how would I know the application is over, if the user don't click the button log out and simply close the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Consider seriuosly using a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). It will make your life easier:)
For example when you authenticate a user, you just grab a connection from the pool, do the validation and then close the connection, which will return it to the pool.

Comment: Can you give me an example or a link?

Comment: I can't close the connection, it will be used for the queries

Comment: The point is that you don't have one global connection which you keep. When you need a connection, you just get it from the pool and return it immediately after you are ready with the current operation.

Comment: You will register the connection pool in the application server and then you will lookup the datasource through JNDI. After that you get a connection from the datasource.

Comment: Here is a simple class for obtaining a connection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915992/proper-usage-of-jdbc-connection-pool-glassfish

Answer (score 1):

> At apllication start the jdbc connection is instantiated

This is the wrong approach. The connection should be opened in the very same `try` block as you're creating and executing the statement and gathering the results. The connection (and statement and resultset) must be closed in the `finally` block of this `try` block.

Not doing so may lead to resource leaking and unexpected (and undesired) application behaviour when this happens and/or when the DB server decides to timeout the connection because it's been kept open for too long by your application.

The following is the basic JDBC idiom:

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(SOME_SQL);
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    // ...
} finally {
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

To improve connecting performance, you can always use a connection pool, but do **not** change the basic JDBC idiom of acquiring and closing the resources in the shortest scope in a `try-finally` block. Most decent servletcontainer/applicationservers ships with builtin connection pooling facilities. As long as it's unclear which one you're using, it's impossible to give a well-suited answer about it.

That said, I would still strongly recommend to detach the persistence layer from your MVC layer. It'll make it better testable, reuseable and maintainable.

#### See also:

- [Basic DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)