# Singleton and DataSource

Tags: java, web-applications, singleton, jndi, connection-pooling

I'm developing a web application with Java and it needs a connection with a data base. **Well administration of resources is very important**. The application will be in a Tomcat 6 servlet container, and I've implemented **BoneCP** to manage connections (I can't use Spring).

I've read that **JNDI lookup for DataSource is too much expensive** and I'm thinking about creating a singleton of DataSource object, to get the JNDI resource only once, and return the same DataSource for future connections.

Question: **Is it a good idea to create a DataSource only once, and get connections from the same DataSource?** I don't want to get the same connection, only the same DataSource.

Thank you ;)

Comment: You should be creating a single datasource and get connections from the pool implemmented in data source.

Answer (score 4):

Use a pooling datasource, such as is described here:

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as Renjith suggested, you only need to create the `DataSource` one time. I actually ran into this same issue yesterday. Every time in my "getConnection" method I noticed I was creating a new InitialContext and DataSource unnecessarily. I revised my Connection Manager class to have a static block of code that creates the DataSource object only when the class gets loaded the first time (after reading BalusC's answer in [Proper usage of JDBC Connection Pool (Glassfish)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915992/proper-usage-of-jdbc-connection-pool-glassfish))

I thought about using the old-school `ServiceLocator` pattern (see Pascal's answer in the above link), but I felt it was a bit too overkill for my needs.

Another possibility is that you could also use the `@Resource` annotation with injection on the DataSources, but that **doesn't** seem to work with `Tomcat 7`.