# Handling exceptions on an EJB when using @Resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I recently have been working on code that periodically imports some data from an old database my company is in the process of phasing out.  I set up a connection pool on glassfish for the old database, which I then inject as a datasource via the @Resource annotation.  It works well, except when the database is unavailable.  In that situation, the server dumps an entire stack trace to the logs related to a javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException.  That makes sense, given that the resource look up is throwing a SQLException (related to not being able to access the database).  What I am not clear on is where to catch and handle the exception, since it is really happening outside of the bean.

Is there a way for an EJB to handle exceptions that occur when resources are being injected into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that level of control/recovery over the connection, manually create it instead of injecting it:

```
try {
  Context ctx = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDBResource");
  Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
  ...
}
catch (Exception exc) {
  ...
}
```

See [additional material for "old style" connection management](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918482/1448212).

Comment: Manual construction is something I would like to avoid.  However, this does seem to indicate that the best approach would be to just fetch the resource via JNDI in the code that needs it and handle the error there.