# Where to initialise database connection for Jersey based application

Tags: java, jersey

I'm new to Java web programming and I'm trying to setup Jersey based application.

I need to setup database connection pool and I'm struggling with finding a good example of how to do it (in the best possible way). From my understanding it should happen in Servlet's init() method. I read something about ServletContextListener which can be setup in web.xml but I don't think that my container (Glassfish) supports web.xml.

One more question is what will happen if a database disconnects? If I establish connection on init() which is run only once how should I reconnect?

//edit: I think that the big part of my problem was being convinced that Grizzly is my container (instead of Glassfish, as pointed out below)

Comment: You mean Glassfish as container, not Grizzly.

Comment: You are right. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set up the connection pool in code. You will use the administration console provided by Glassfish to set this up:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#gharo

In terms of getting a connection, you simply inject a DataSource into your code using CDI:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/mydatabase")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

where name is the JNDI name for the datasource.

> Java EE 7:
> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html
>
> Java EE 6:
> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html

In terms of connection pool management, you don't need to worry about it in code. The container will handle all that for you. Obviously, via the admin console, you can configure its properties.

You will find a good answer from Pascal Thivent here in terms of looking up resources and the history of it (prior to Java EE 6):
[Proper usage of JDBC Connection Pool (Glassfish)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915992/proper-usage-of-jdbc-connection-pool-glassfish)

Comment: Sorry for being thick but I run my application with `mvn exec:java'. How do I access the admin console?

Comment: That command suggests your code will run, perhaps in an embedded environment. Glassfish is something you install separately and deploy your built application onto.

Answer (score 0):

Define it as a datasource in the application server (i.e. Glassfish) and look it up using JNDI.